# Play local videos in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-video-player

I need to play a asset video in my app but the vide player plugin keeps on buffering but didn't play the video. But if I use network videos then the code works perfectly.

Here is my code,

```
class LandscapePlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LandscapePlayerState createState() => _LandscapePlayerState();
}

class _LandscapePlayerState extends State<LandscapePlayer> {
  FlickManager flickManager;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flickManager = FlickManager(videoPlayerController:
         VideoPlayerController.asset('videos/first.mp4',),);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    flickManager.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FlickVideoPlayer(
        flickManager: flickManager,
        preferredDeviceOrientation: [
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft
        ],
        systemUIOverlay: [],
        flickVideoWithControls: FlickVideoWithControls(
          controls: LandscapePlayerControls(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have added the video file as a dependency in pubspec.yaml file. I don't know why it works for network files but not for asset file.

Comment: Which error do you get? Did you check if path `videos/first.mp4` is correct?

Comment: I didn't get any error while debugging. But the video is not playing. Yes, the path is correct.

Comment: I see extra comma there. Maybe try removing that? Like:  `VideoPlayerController.asset("videos/first.mp4")`

Comment: Nope, it doesn't make any difference

Comment: Any idea what's wrong in this?

Comment: How did you set it in pubspec.yaml? Maybe try with `VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/videos/first.mp4")`?

Comment: Thank you, I solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue. [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) plugin uses Exo player plugin in android which is not working correctly in some devices(due to decoders or something). An easy alternative is to go by [native_video_view](https://github.com/LJaraCastillo/native_video_view) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `VideoPlayerController`, to add this run

```
flutter pub add video_player
```

create a folder for video files named it `videos` and mention this folder in `pubspec.yaml` file under `assets` like this:

```
assets:
 - images/
 - videos/
```

and then initialise player in `initState` method follow steps mentioned here:
[Implement video player in flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/plugins/play-video)

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the file path like this: "file://foldername/file.extension"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well. But one thing I noticed was, some sample videos from the Internet weren't working. The error I was getting was "Video codec error".
So, I downloaded the working ones and put them in the assets folder. To my surprise, those files worked.
After digging a lot, and a lot of trial-error, running this command to scale down the resolution on the files that didn't work, did the trick.

```
ffmpeg -i source_file.mp4 -vf "scale=640:360" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -c:a copy target_file.mp4
```